# MySQL multiple And and or match no result

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, multiple-columns

i have a table with many fields

my statement:

```
select * from
[table]
WHERE
(field1 LIKE 'test%' or field2 LIKE 'test%')
AND
(field1 LIKE 'foo%' or field2 LIKE 'foo%')
AND
public='1'
```

I have a record with: field1='foobar',field2='testing',public='1' but the query doenst match this one!

can anyone help?

Comment: You should make sure there are no white spaces at the beginning of those strings in database

Comment: Your query, as written in the question, should match the data that you  provide.  You should look for leading spaces, hidden characters, or characters that look similar in your character set.

Comment: i think your condition is wrong.. both conditin are not satisfy at a time

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle (at www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try:

```
select * from
[table]
WHERE
(ltrim(field1) LIKE 'test%' or ltrim(field2) LIKE 'test%')
AND
(ltrim(field1) LIKE 'foo%' or ltrim(field2) LIKE 'foo%')
AND
public='1'
```

I expect you have some white spaces at the beginning of your strings in database

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with trim() function like

```
select * from
[table]
WHERE
(trim(field1) LIKE 'test%' or trim(field2) LIKE 'test%')
AND
(trim(field1) LIKE 'foo%' or trim(field2) LIKE 'foo%')
AND
public='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
field1='foobar', field2='testing', public='1'
```

If you required Above record then try This

```
select * from
[table]
WHERE
(field1 LIKE 'test%' AND field2 LIKE 'foo%')
OR
(field1 LIKE 'foo%' AND field2 LIKE 'test%')
AND
public='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try thiz one**

```
select * from [table] WHERE ((conact(field1,field2) LIKE '%test%' ) and(conact(field1,field2) LIKE '%foo%')) AND public='1'
```